# How to call a view from a view in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-view

I need to render a view from inside a view.

For the sake of question, i'll call them blocks.

I have 5 controllers, each of them has an action that is called **BlockAction()**, and it displays some of the information from that controller.

In the Index page for the whole website I need to call all 5 of those BlockAction views. What could be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look into [`Zend_Layout`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.introduction.html), I believe you will find it to be a more abstract solution and give you more control over the views.  Basically the "layout" is the view which has multiple views within it (Redundant I know).

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the already given answers.

While the approach to have separate controllers and action for blocks is most true to the classic MVC approach, where each part of the UI has it's corresponding controller, it is not advisable to use it with Zend Framework.

In theory you could use the [ActionStack Action Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) or [Action View helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html) to call the controller actions. However this would make your application go through the full dispatch cycle for each call.

Further reading:

- [Why the Zend Framework Actionstack is Evil](http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/)

Comment: Thanks, for the tip, I'll try to work on this issue.

Comment: just to avoid some potential confusion.  The action stack is called when using view helpers.  When using partial views, the actionstack is not invoked